# saving rejected records in another rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading logs and parsing them in spark. If the parsing fails, I am saving that line in an arraybuffer and then proceeding with parsing.
Once parsing is complete, I parallelize that array buffer into and RDD and write to HDFS.

This works well locally but the problem is  when I try and run it in a cluster mode, the arraybuffer is probably lost by the time write action is called. Any suggestion how do I deal with it?

If I try and creating an rdd with rejected records within map method,  I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:370)
```

Comment: I would do something like: `def parse(line: String): Either[Error, Log] = ???` Then: `val parsed = data.map(parse).cache()` - `val errors = parsed.collect { case Left(error) => error }` - `val logs = parsed.collect { case Right(log) => log }`

Comment: Can we see some sample code please?